# Caching and gzip when using jQuery UI from Google CDN

Tags: jquery, google-api

I use the Google CDN URL for getting jQuery UI. But when I tested using YSlow I found that the both js/css are not gzipped although other components from server were gzipped and had expires (it does a content modified check).  Should I add anything to the URL to let  the browser know  that it should cache, and get the gzipped content?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks gzipped and properly set to expire to me...

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js

```
Last-Modified: Mon, 08 Jun 2009 20:49:31 GMT
Content-Type: application/x-javascript; charset=UTF-8
Expires: Fri, 09 Jul 2010 17:22:01 GMT
Date: Thu, 09 Jul 2009 17:22:01 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Server: GFE/2.0

200 OK
```

Answer (score 1):

Getting the gzip or not is dependent upon both the browser and the server.  If the browser can't accept gzip, it won't request it.  If the server doesn't support gzipping, then even if the browser requests it, it won't respond with gzip.  There's nothing you can do about it.  Also the expires header is set on the server side, so there is nothing you can do about it either.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is dependent on the request message send by the browser, if it will send the Accept encoding to gzip, it might get it if the server support it.

e.g take this http request message.

```
GET google HTTP/1.1
Host: aajtak.intoday.in
Accept: */*
Accept-Charset: iso-8859-1, utf-8; q=0.7, *; q=0.7
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, x-gzip, identity; q=0.9
Accept-Language: en;q=1.0,zh-cn, zh;q=0.5
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (SymbianOS/9.1; U; en-us) AppleWebKit/413 (KHTML, like Gecko) Safari/413
```